# Django Makemigrations and Migrate keep repeating

Tags: python, django, django-models

Something seems to be occurring with my django app. There are two models, one where I altered and the other a new addition. Ever since these two changes my `makemigrations` and `migrate` has continued to be the same changed with the migration number incrementing.
When I `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'om':
  0033_auto_20200122_0001.py:
    - Alter field delivery_date on growerpurchaseorderitem
Migrations for 'accounts':
  0105_auto_20200122_0001.py:
    - Alter field created on pushtoken
    - Alter field push_token on pushtoken
```

And when I `migrate`

```
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying accounts.0105_auto_20200122_0001... OK
  Applying om.0033_auto_20200122_0001... OK
```

I have tried to fake a migration to get past this but no luck. It is an issue as any new changes are not registering to my models.

EDIT:

Show migrations:

for my om

```
[X] 0030_auto_20200121_2339
 [X] 0031_auto_20200121_2343
 [X] 0032_auto_20200121_2348
 [X] 0033_auto_20200122_0001
```

for my accounts

```
[X] 0099_certpdf_expiration_date
 [X] 0100_pushtoken
 [X] 0101_auto_20200121_2145
 [X] 0102_auto_20200121_2339
 [X] 0103_auto_20200121_2343
 [X] 0104_auto_20200121_2348
 [X] 0105_auto_20200122_0001
```

Comment: Are the migrations actually changing your database?

Comment: Can you add the migration files?

Comment: @GregKaleka yeah I can view them from the dashboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django keeps migrating the same foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856506/django-keeps-migrating-the-same-foreign-key)

Comment: Added migration files @gdef_

Comment: @HarshNagarkar unfortunately, no. I don't have that in my meta

Comment: Do your model fileds have changing default values, like for example `datetime.now()`?

Comment: @KlausD. yes. I have used that before though. Is it the issue?

Comment: Most likely. Try to remove the parentheses! Django should do the call if needed only.

Comment: fixed it. turns out when i went to remove the parentheses i found that i also had something along the lines of `blank=true,null=true` causing this to happen. Thank you @KlausD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, this is most likely the point where the program gets awry:

```py
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
```

Try creating the migrations and then fake the first migration:

```py
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Where the commands will skip any migration where the tables were already created.

P.S. If you don't know what fake migrations are, [check out the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem with migrate, just delete lastly auto created files in the migrations folder and do it again.

You can also edit it directly and run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```